# Valid anchor on multiple spans

Tags: html, css

I have following html:

```
    <p class="main-text">
      <span>Lorem Ipsum</span>
      <span>Lorem Ipsum</span>
      <span>Lorem Ipsum</span>
      <span>Lorem Ipsum</span>
      <span>Lorem Ipsum.</span>
    </p>
```

And css:

```
.main-text > span {
    display: inline-block;
}
```

I need to apply single anchor on all spans that when user hover only on text he can click the link.
Is there possible way without using multiple anchors like that..?

```
      <p class="main-text">
        <a href="same url">
          <span>Lorem Ipsum</span>
        </a>
        <a href="same url">
          <span>Lorem Ipsum</span>
        </a>
        <a href="same url">
          <span>Lorem Ipsum</span>
        </a>
        <a href="same url">
          <span>Lorem Ipsum</span>
        </a>
        <a href="same url">
          <span>Lorem Ipsum.</span>
        </a>
      </p>
```

Thank you

Comment: The solution would be to use html preprocessor like Pug. Then you would be able to use loops.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you meant

```css
.main-text>a>span {
  display: inline-block;
}
a { text-decoration:none }
```

```html
<p class="main-text">
  <a href="https://www.lipsum.com/">
    <span>Lorem Ipsum</span>
    <span>Lorem Ipsum</span>
    <span>Lorem Ipsum</span>
    <span>Lorem Ipsum</span>
    <span>Lorem Ipsum.</span>
  </a>
</p>
```

Or this

```js
document.querySelector(".main-text").addEventListener("click", function(e) {
  const tgt = e.target;
  if (tgt.tagName == "SPAN") location = "https://www.lipsum.com/";
})
```

```css
.main-text>span {
  display: inline-block;
  cursor: pointer
}
```

```html
<p class="main-text">
  <span>Lorem Ipsum</span>
  <span>Lorem Ipsum</span>
  <span>Lorem Ipsum</span>
  <span>Lorem Ipsum</span>
  <span>Lorem Ipsum.</span>
</p>
```

Comment: Agreed, and additionally for the first part the CSS should probably use `.main-text > a > span`.

Comment: Hm yea,
thing here is that css `.main-text>a>span {
  display: inline-block;
}` is useless and I should use <br/> to separate spans on single lines then.

Comment: Why useless? Looks the same as your code makes it look?

Answer (score 0):

If you want all the `<span>` tags to direct to the same link and you want users to be able to click on the `<span>` tags but not in the spaces between them, you can use something like this.

```css
.main-text a {
  pointer-events: none;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.main-text a span {
  pointer-events: auto;
}
```

```html
<p class="main-text">
  <a href="https://google.com">
    <span>1</span>
    <span>2</span>
    <span>3</span>
    <span>4</span>
    <span>5</span>
  </a>
</p>
```